# Visual Studio Code Analysis (fxCop) run only after the first build

Tags: visual-studio-2010, msbuild, code-analysis, fxcop

I've created a custom fxCop Rules and integrated them in visual studio 2010 by following
[this tutorial](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/codeanalysis/archive/2010/03/26/how-to-write-custom-static-code-analysis-rules-and-integrate-them-into-visual-studio-2010.aspx)

Everything seemed to work just fine except that the fxCop rules are running only on the first build after I make any change in the source code (even just adding a space). Additional builds, (without making any changes in the source code) do not produce any FxCop warrning.

I'm guessing it has something to do with that fact c# MSbuild "Build" target doesn't really re-compile if the source files timestamps are the same as the last compiled assembly timestamp

How can I make the FxCop Code Analysis to run every build?

Answer (score 1):

A couple of things come to mind:

1. Because as you say, MSBuild may decide the build target is up to date, you could try [running FxCop as a post-build step](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/codeanalysis/archive/2007/02/24/faq-how-do-i-run-fxcop-during-a-post-build-event.aspx).
2. Code Analysis creates a .CodeAnalysisLog.xml and .lastcodeanalysiscucceeded file fore each analysed file. Maybe deleting these files before building would also help.